# Array copy, second one without last position

Tags: java, android

I am trying to copy two array, but the second one don’t have the last position.

Ex: array1 = 1234
    array2 = 123

The final objective is to show the second array in the screen of a application, but when I send this the screen become with 0 value.
Can anyone help me?

here is the code:

```
public void deletar(String visor_)
{
     //visor=screen.getText().toString();
     int a,b;
     char [] deletar1 = visor.toCharArray();
     char [] deletar2={'a'};

     for (a=0;a<deletar1.length-1;a++)
     {
         for(b=0;b<deletar2.length;b++)
         {
              deletar2[b]=deletar1[a];
         }
     }

     screen.setText(String.valueOf(deletar2));       
 }
```

Comment: what are you actually trying to do :S .. i am really confused

Comment: HINT: You inner `for` should be an `if`

Comment: Remove that -1 from `deletar1.length-1`. It should be `deletar1.length`

Answer (score 1):

By using System.arraycopy() and specifying a length you can achieve your desired results without having to loop and figure it out on your own.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/system_arraycopy.htm

Example:

```
char [] l1 = {'a','b','c'};
char [] l2 = new char[l1.length - 1];
System.arraycopy(l1, 0, l2, 0, l1.length-1);
```

Of course this code would not be safe if l1 had a length of 0.

Comment: What about [substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,int))?

Comment: He asked specifically about copying the data in an array form, not a String form.  substring is a better solution though more generally.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this one-line solution using [String#subString(int beginIndex, int endIndex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) :

```
String str = visor.subString(0,visor.length()-2);
```

Comment: He wanted to copy the data when it's in an array form, not a String form.  Obviously, that's a good String solution.

Comment: @davecom I am not sure about what the OP really wants. The title indicates an array copy but the API suggests that the real need is to work on a String. In doubt, I also upvote your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code:

```
public void deletar(String visor_)
{
     //visor=screen.getText().toString();
     int a,b;
     char [] deletar1 = visor.toCharArray();
     char [] deletar2={'a'};

     for (a=0;a<deletar1.length;a++)
     {
         for(b=0;b<deletar2.length;b++)
         {
              deletar2[b]=deletar1[a];
         }
     }

     screen.setText(String.valueOf(deletar2));       
 }
```